# PHP session_destroy() stopped working

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

session_destroy() stopped working recently due to unknown reasons and now the active session is not getting destroyed. I have tried all the solutions mentioned on SE but they are not working. Below is the code that I am using.

```
session_start(); # NOTE THE SESSION START
$_SESSION = array(); 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: thankyou');
exit();
```

**Entire script:**

```
<?php
    //session_start();

    $to = 'equote@domain.com';


    $products = $_POST['product_id'];
    $subject = "Request Quote";
    $errors = array();
    $i = 0;
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || $_POST['name'] == ''){
        $errors[$i] = 'Please enter your Name';
        $i++;
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['company_name']) || $_POST['company_name'] == ''){
        $errors[$i] = 'Please enter your Company Name';
        $i++;
    } 

    if(!isset($_POST['phone']) || $_POST['phone'] == ''){
        $errors[$i] = 'Please enter your Phone Number';
        $i++;
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['email']) || $_POST['email'] == ''){
        $errors[$i] = 'Please enter your Email';
        $i++;
    }
    /*if($_POST['email2'] != $_POST['email'] ){
        $errors[$i] = 'Your Email does not match';
        $i++;
    }*/  

    if($i > 0){
        $msg = serialize($errors);
        $info = serialize ($_POST);
        header('Location: /checkout/cart/?msg='.$msg.'&info='.$info);
        exit;
    }
    $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $company_name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['company_name']);
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $fax = $_POST['fax'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $contact_by = $_POST['contact_by'];
    $sales_person = $_POST['sales_person'];
    $items = '';
    foreach($products as $product){
        $items .= $product . ',';
    }

    //connect to the DB!!
    mysql_connect('localhost','machiner_dbusr','d2eV3k98Zx76YgZ');
    mysql_select_db('machiner_db');
    $date = date('m-d-Y');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `quote` (`name`, `company_name`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `country`, `phone`, `fax`, `email`, `contact_by`, `item_skus`, `date`) VALUES ('$name', '$company_name', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$country', '$phone', '$fax', '$email', '$contact_by', '$items', '$date')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($products as $product){
        $entity_id = 0;
        $product = str_replace(' ','',$product);
        $sql = "SELECT `entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` ='$product'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $entity_id = $row['entity_id'];
        }
        if($entity_id != 0){
            $sql = "SELECT `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE `entity_id` ='$entity_id' AND `attribute_id` ='58'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $product_name[$i] = $row['value'];
            } 
            $sql = "SELECT `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `entity_id` ='$entity_id' AND `attribute_id` ='446'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $location[$i] = $row['value'];
            } 
        } else{
            $product_name[$i] = '';
        }
        $i++;
    }


    $message = '';

    $message .= 'Company Name: '.$_POST['company_name']. "\n";
    //$message .= 'Address: '.$_POST['address']. "\n";
    //$message .= 'City: '.$_POST['city']. "\n";
    //$message .= 'State: '.$_POST['state']. "\n";
    //$message .= 'Zip Code: '.$_POST['zip']. "\n";
    $message .= 'Country: '.$_POST['country']. "\n";
    $message .= 'Name of Person: '.$_POST['name'] . "\n";
    $message .= 'Phone: '.$_POST['phone']. "\n";
    /*$message .= 'Fax: '.$_POST['fax']. "\n";*/
    $message .= 'Email: '.$_POST['email']. "\n\r";
    $message .= 'Comments: '.$_POST['comments']. "\n\r";
    $message .= 'Inventory Items:'. "\n";
    //$message .= '<table cellpadding="5" width="100%">'. "\n\r";
    //$message .= '<thead>'. "\n\r";
    //$message .= '</thead>'. "\n\r";
    //$message .= '<tbody>'. "\n\r";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($products as $product){
        $message .= 'Stock Number:   '. $product. "\n";
        $message .= 'Description:   '. $product_name[$i]. "\n";
        $message .= 'Location:      '. $location[$i] . "\n\r";
        //$message .= '<tr><td>'.$product.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$product_name[$i].'</td><td>'.$location[$i].'</td>'.'</tr>'. "\n\r";
        $i++;
    }
    //$message .= '</tbody>'. "\n\r";
    //$message .= '</table>'. "<br />\n\r";

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
//$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// Additional headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$_POST['email'].'>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

session_start(); # NOTE THE SESSION START
$_SESSION = array(); 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: thankyou');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: "session_destroy() stopped working recently " ... well, what has changed recently?

Comment: nothing changed. We are using Magento as a custom quote request system. Once the product is submitted as quote request the is sent as an email as coded above in the question and get the product cleared from cart but the cart stopped getting cleared recently.

Answer (score 0):

I just clear $_SESSION, and it always works for me.

```
<?
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

then you must user $_SESSION in your script.